# Update front fields in the database

Tags: angular, angular-material, crud

I have a project in Angular and Spring in which I am implementing `CRUD` operations but I am having trouble updating the fields in the database.

My **problem**: how can I communicate the ts function with the service to send the new data to the back and update the database?

This is my `service.ts` with the edit function:

```
public edit(cliente: Cliente): Observable<Cliente> {
      console.log('edit: ' + `${PREFIX}/${cliente.id}`, cliente);
      return this.http.post<Cliente>(`${PREFIX}/${cliente.id}`, cliente);
    }
```

This is the function that I currently have in the ts to save the changes but I don't know how to communicate it with the service to send it the new data:

```
saveEdit() {
    this.editIndex = -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to import your service on your component. ej

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
import {MyService} from 'path/to/my-service.ts';
export class EditComponent{
constructor(private myService: MyService){}
}
```

- Then use it in `saveEdit` method, ej

```js
saveEdit():void {
const client = .....; // I dont know how do you get this, maybe from a form like `this.myForm.value`
 this.myService.edit(client).subscribe({ next:(response) => {
console.log(response);
// Here the success response
}, error: (e) => {
console.log(e);
// Here on error
} });
}
```

PS. I dont speak english very well